# How to install MSVCR90D.DLL

Tags: visual-c++, msvcr90d.dll, msvcr90.dll

How do I install MSVCR90D.DLL?  I have a small test DLL(debug mode) that I created a setup project.  In my setup project, I included merge modules & policy for vc90_debugcrt_x86.msm, etc.  When I install the DLL on my VM, dependency walker still reports that MSVCR90D.DLL cannot be found?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985618%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

> Preparing a Test Machine To Run a
>   Debug Executable

Microsoft does not officially support deploying debug runtimes outside of dev/test environments but you can make it work if you need to.  Sounds like this is a vanilla test environment installation, though.

Answer (score 2):

Just copy the MSVCR90D.DLL file into the same directory as your own dll. Then both your dll and dependency walker will find the MSVCR90D.DLL file.

You may need a couple of other files like msvcp90d.dll or msvcm90d.dll but dependency walker knows if you need them for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

MSVCR90D.DLL is the debug version of the Visual Studio Runtime Libraries.  Normally, if you're deploying that code, you would build it in Release mode and also provide/install the Visual Studio Runtime Redistributable.  As far as I know, the only way to obtain the debug dlls are through a Visual Studio install.

Answer (score 0):

The py2exe utility that converts Python scripts into executable Windows programs seems to have   a similar problem [here](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step52). Maybe the section "Bundling the C runtime DLL" helps you to find the solution.