# Visual C++ MSVCR90.dll is missing

Tags: visual-c++, msvcr90d.dll

I've been seeing this error many times in Visual Studio 2008 professional.
"The program can't start because MSVCR90.dll is missing ..."

I am seeing this on 2 different machines at work and all project files are on the local drives except one of them that is on an external USB drive.

This error sometimes goes away by clean/rebuilding the whole project. 
At other times I've been able to get rid of it by turning off the incremental link.

Does anybody have further insight?

Thanks, 
Bezad

Comment: do you have http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=29  ?

Comment: @majatu note tag [msvcr90d.dll]. note 'd' at end. I've repaired my ms vc 2008 redists with both sp1 and 'basic', but I have no file named msvcr90d.dll with 'd' at the end in my file system. From Q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389958/how-to-install-msvcr90d-dll I see I would need the Debug dll, not the release. I have no vs2008 currently, only the redist. no official support for installing msvcr90d.dll (without vs)? I need a dev machine.

Comment: please clarify if you need msvcr90.dll (you wrote it in title, text body) *or* msvcr90d.dll (as in msvcr90**d**.dll) (you wrote it in tags)

Comment: The message I get is MSVCR90.dll is missing ...

Comment: Are you getting the same error?

Comment: I have now confirmed that by turning off incremental linking I can always get rid of it